# Changing TextField value without triggering TextListener

Tags: java, listener, awt, textfield

I have a `TextListener` I want to change programatically without triggering its `TextListener`. I just want the text listener to activate on user text changing.
How should I proceed ?

```
TextField human = new TextField();
human.addTextListener(myListener);

// I don't want this line to trigger listener
human.setText(myString);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could remove and re-add the listener or give it a boolean to toggle when it should listen.

Edit: per Tom Hawtin: the second recommendation, the one to use a flag, is much preferred over adding/removing a listener, and this makes sense to me as well.

Comment: Using a flag is going to be much better than playing about adding and removing listeners. (Could also use proxy Documents to detect which sources that changes are coming from.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: thanks for your valuable input. I have edited my answer to reflect your recommendation. Could you explain more or provide a link about use of proxy documents (or feel free to edit my answer)? Thanks!

Comment: and in fact that AWT rellated answerers wholesale died in last century :-)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Is there a method to toggle Listener activation ?

Comment: @mKorbel, you mean I should find an equivalent in Swing ?

Comment: use DocumentListener for JTextComponents